# How do I change the name on my @me.com email.com?

Tags: icloud

I'm divorced now and I've updated my name in iCloud but when I send an email from @me.com email my hyphenated name still comes up. How do I change that?

Comment: You might want to add a screen shot of what you are doing or some context to help. There is a web interface to iCloud, Windows and Mac and iOS all can send emails. The icloud.com mail interface should let you change the name...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're trying to change your full name (and not the email address itself), you can follow the directions in this [Cnet article](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57509815-263/how-to-change-your-icloud-mail-full-name/):

> First log into iCloud.com, then click the Mail icon to open the
>   Webmail application. In the Webmail application, click the gear at the
>   top right and choose "Preferences" from the menu that appears, and you
>   should see a window that appears with settings specific to your e-mail
>   account. Click the Accounts section and you should see editable fields
>   for Description and Full Name. Fill in your desired full name to
>   display, and save the settings.
>
> [image]
>
> **Note**: Image courtesy of Cnet

Your updated full name should then be used by the @me.com email address. The article also discusses how to change the displayed full name in the OS X mail client, but this example is a bit more generic.